# design issue about multiple parameters in a function

Tags: java, object, design-patterns, parameters

first of all I'm using java, even though it could be a question for any language

say I have a complicated system, now sometimes I end up building objects (setting all the parameters), then passing it over to a "target layer"(manager), which opens the object (getting the parameters).

if I were to pass all the parameters in one function, it would be considered poor design, because there's suppose to be a small amount of parameters per function

this seems like a waste, and in the past I also decided to set the parameters straight to the "target layer"

is there a design pattern that deals with this issue?
or something that books or experts in the subject recommend?

Comment: have you tried for static variables and functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might take a look on the Effective Java Book that will cover Design method signatures carefully

There will be three techniques for shortening long parameters :

- break the method into multiple methods, each which require only a subset of the parameters
- create helper classes to hold group of parameters (typically static member classes)
- adapt the Builder
  pattern from object construction to method invocation

Since you're asking the reference, I hope it can help solve your problem and don't forget to buy the book [here](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA15&dq=java%20bloch%20effective%20builder%20methods&ei=zi6aS6DUHY30Mr_fsdIH&cd=1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=design%20method%20signatures&f=false)

Comment: thank you, your answer was the most comprehensive, I think I'll buy that book

Comment: You are most welcome and glad that I can help. Keep working on

Answer (score 1):

Since you were asking about book references, here is one from [*Clean Code*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), Chapter 3: Functions:

> When a function seems to need more than two or three arguments, it is
>   likely that some of those arguments ought to be wrapped into a class
>   of their own. [...]
>
> Reducing the number of arguments by creating objects out of them may
>   seem like cheating, but it’s not. When groups of variables are passed
>   together, [...] they are likely part
>   of a concept that deserves a name of its own.

So I guess it's ok to group a lot of method arguments into classes, as long as these classes represent some coherent concepts.

Personally if I do something like this, I like the wrapper class to be immutable and created by a dedicated builder. Which increases the number of additional classes twofold (wrapper and the builder), but enables the treatment of such a class as one atomic argument.

Comment: thank you, I one upped you, but there was a more comprehensive answer, I agree with your claim, and I do have a coherent concept, the builder pattern is I think my issue here

Comment: No problem, I also liked the answer you chose (in fact, I upvoted it before writing my own).

Answer (score 1):

Extract the parameters into its own "Parameter-Object" (pattern name) and pass that object to the function. 
If the Parameter-Object itself is complicated to construct, use the Builder-Pattern which simplifies the construction if the object can be constructed in different ways.

For Example:

```
function(param1, param2, param3, ...)
```

The parameters are then extracted into an Object:

```
class ParamObject {
  param1;
  param2;
  param3;
}
```

with its corresponding setters and getters.

To construct the ParamObject use the [BuilderPattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/the-builder-pattern-in-practice.html).

And finally, the invocation would look like this:

```
function(paramobject):
```

Inside the function the former arguments are then retreived from the object.
As siledh stated: Make sure to group arguments into classes that share a common concept, which means that it´s ok to create several classes out of the paramlist.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Data Transfer Object to me.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html

Comment: a DTO carries data between different processes, and I'm talking about the same package, thank you also for your answer though